# How to serialize and send a MailMessage over a WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following error when i try to perform a POST operation to WebAPI from C#.

The error I am getting is : `"Error getting value from 'replacementFallback' on 'System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback'".`

Calling API from C#

```
EmailReportVM mailMsgRpt = new EmailReportVM();

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
             {
             // Add an Accept header for JSON format
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
             //response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(InsertMailSendQueueapiURL, mailMsgRpt).Result;
             response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(InsertMailSendQueueapiURL, mailMsgRpt).Result;
             }
```

It seems the error is happening because `Newtonsoft.Json` is unbale to serialize the property called mailMsg which is of type `MailMessage` to Json.

What should I do in order to overcome this issue.

EmailReportVM :

```
 public class EmailReportVM 
    {

        public EmailReportVM ()
        {
          PhotoUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotoUrl"];
        }

        public string from {get; set;};
        public string to {get; set;};
.....
        public MailMessage mailMsg { get; set; }

    }
```

the Body of the mailMsg looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td{font-size:14px;font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;}
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Your Agent Contact Information</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td width="90%">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong>Agent Name:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Juan Miguel 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong>Agent Phone:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        300-300-1100
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong>Agent Fax:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        800-700-2700
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong>E-mail Address:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        user1@dev.themls.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <p style="font-size:14px;font-family:verdana,arial;">Check out this report.</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:65355/Stats/EmailedReports/AXoaIbi60eNsKNl_w3jr2Q2">
        <img alt="click here" src="http://www.thempd.com/images/click_here.gif" /></a> to view your report.  <br />

    <br />    
</body>
</html>
```